# Why is assembly + C++ question about stack not a real question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316371/why-are-the-stack-addresses-different-wrong

I clearly tagged it as x86 and C++. I described the problem, showed the assembly, showed the C++ code which generated that assembly and clearly asked my question (which is one address appear to be on the stack and the other appear not to be (its 0xD)). I can't understand why it isn't a real question as i clearly state it and provided code.

Comment: You provided all the extra detail after the post was closed. The question that was closed seems to be the first revision. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13316371/revisions

Comment: "Why is my car making a funny noise?" is a real question in dictionary termss, but not on the SE sites. To be a real question it has to include enough information for people to be able to answer it. And the commenters have made it very clear that you have not provided that.

Comment: @KateGregory: I provided the details. There was a link required because it was large and SO doesnt format it correctly but i did provide it

Comment: @Bart: All i did was copy/paste from a link i included. But not copy/pasting it in doesnt warrant a close does it?

Comment: With much of the relevant detail being external to SO I can't say I'm surprised. I might have given you some time to edit before voting to close, but some don't. And you should know by now that closure is not necessarily permanent.

Comment: Btw, isn't it a dupe of your earlier closed question to begin with? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314439/why-is-this-0xd-on-stack

Comment: @Bart: My ealier question was how to debug it and one person in the comments actually helped. The other question is why is the variable on the stack wonkey. I also know once its close its hard to reopen and I never knew providing a link VS copying paste something (which wouldnt be formatted the same on SO) is bad.

Comment: Seems to me it's too localized no matter, but perhaps it is now moot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[At the time it was closed you didn't provide the code, you only provided a link to an external site that had the code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13316371/1).

Let's assume the external site went down, how could we know what the full details of your problem were?  We couldn't.

If you're going to provide a link to an external source on the Stack Exchange network, it should only be * supplemental*, if the link is removed, the content of the post should still be valid.

That was not the case before [the edit that you made to include the code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13316371/2).

Comment: Are you saying including a link rather then copy/pasting it all is warrants a close rather then a comment and either a downvote or mod doing it? I dont think that warrants a close

Comment: @acidzombie24 It does.  Note the close description for "Not A Real Question" (emphasis mine): "This question is ambiguous, vague, **incomplete**..."  The fact that the code is on another site makes the post incomplete.

Comment: I don't know whos stupid decision it was that linking warrants a close but i'll accept anyways