# Why isn't this a real question? "Assembly: C++ stack variable addresses different/wrong?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I wrote the question [Assembly: C++ stack variable addresses different/wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317010/assembly-c-stack-variable-addresses-different-wrong), and it was closed as not a real question.

The FAQ says

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this
>   question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

The question isn't ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical. I supplied code and assembly and **tagged** it as an *assembly* question. It is reasonably answerable in its current form.

What is the problem with the question?

Comment: Effectively a continuation of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155238/why-is-assembly-c-question-about-stack-not-a-real-question, as the author reposted an expanded version of his deleted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316371/why-are-the-stack-addresses-different-wrong (10k only).

Comment: @dmckee: Apparently the question was invalid since i linked rather then copy/pasted the code. So, i did it properly which means they cant use linking to an external site as an excuse.

Comment: I understand. But when a post makes me go *::boggle:: Didn't we just do this?* I go figure out why and post a brief explanation for others who may be in the same boat. I've no dog in this fight.

Answer (score 6):

You went totally in the other direction. Most questions closed as not a real question are barely a single complete sentence.

In this case, I really think you can get it reopened if you follow these steps:

### Steps to Reopening a Very Long Question:

- Edit the post and add sections/headings. There's a lot of material there, and breaking it up may make it easier to read.
- Highlight your question by making it bold. This will give people a place to start to determine if they want to bother reading the entire post. Put this at the beginning, and repeat it at the end.
- If there is information in your post that's not important to the problem, consider pruning  it out. Sometimes less is more.

### Summary:

On longer posts, if you divide up into sections and use more of the markup, you can make sure your post is easier to digest. Good luck!

Comment: imo it isn't (very) long. Its <250 words which, this question is about 150 so its less then twice as long as this which isnt that long. I'd call it medium but i have written long questions before and i think people are only upset because they have to read assembly and not C++

Comment: Still, you sort of have to keep in mind that whitespace is a very helpful stress reducer. Most people see a long post and their brain shuts down. If you understand this psychology, you can use it to your advantage. Maybe the answer isn't pruning it so much as just putting more breadcrumbs in place to highlight important points. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Close vote seems excessive. The only reason I can think of is: It's not immediately clear what the specific, answerable question is.

I think the question is valid, it's maybe just not worded very clearly

Could you maybe reword the question more along the lines of the standard bug-report format? Steps to reproduce, expected result, actual result.

Also, complete and compilable code would help - if you can reduce your problematic code down to the shortest practical chunk of code to demonstrate the weirdness, it would definitely help the question's "realness"

Comment: Thats as close as i could get it. I finally figured out the problem and it IS shown in that question. Its just in the assembly which no one reads and rather harass me about and closed the question.